# Multiple git repos in one folder?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to have a folder structure on git with multiple repos in it?

For example:

```
<owner>
    <folder 1>
        <folder 1.1>
            <repo>
        <folder 1.2>
            <repo>
        . . .
    <folder 2>
        <folder 2.1>
            <repo>
        <folder 2.2>
            <repo>
        . . .
    <folder 3>
        <folder 3.1>
            <repo>
        <folder 3.2>
            <repo>
        . . .
```

Comment: `on git` - you mean *on Github*?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the *owner* is also a git repository, then take a look at [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Otherwise, I don’t see why not.

Comment: I just want to organize my stuff on git.

Comment: @moki I’m still not sure about the specifics. You tagged the question with #github. Are you organizing the code on your local disk or on GitHub?

Comment: @SyzbkiDanny Im organizing my code on GitHub.
I just want to have multiple folders on git like "c, cpp, php, python" so that I can have for example a hello_world repo written in c in my c folder and a hello_world repo written in python in my python folder..

Comment: @moki I think you should be good with organizing the code into separate repositories on GitHub, the repositories will be automatically marked with a language tag detected by [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist). Then, I’d put them into separate directories on you local storage to group them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have this structure in your remote repo (gitlab, github) I don’t see any obstacles. The same is good for a local repo.

Basically gitlab allows you to create subgroups (folder1, folder 1.2, ...) and put whatever amount of repositories inside this subgroups as you wish.

In your case:

1. **owner** is a base subgroup
2. **folder 1** is the level 1 subgroup
3. **folder 1.1** is the level 2 subgroup
4. **repo** is the repo of the level 2 subgroup
5. **folder 1.2** is the level 2 subgroup
6. **repo** is the repo of the level 2 subgroup

You don’t need git submodules if I got your question right.
Submodules are needed in case if you have to inject one repo inside another as a folder and have its content synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely organize your repos into that folder structure and the question is to how to manage them. I wrote a command-line tool [gita](https://github.com/nosarthur/gita) for this purpose.

It can display the status of all repos, including the edit status, the relation to remote branch, etc. It also batch executes commands from any working directory.

You can also group the repos. For your project structure, you can run

```
gita add -a <owner>
```

which will automatically generate hierarchical groups:

- `owner`: containing all repos
- `owner-folder1`: repos in it
- `owner-folder1-folder1.1`: repos in there
- etc

Then `gita ll owner`, `gita ll owner-folder1`, etc will display the relevant information. `gita <command> owner` will batch run the command on repos in the owner group. You can also run any command on any specified repos from any working directory too.

There are other functionalities such as setting context, defining custom commands, etc. Installation is `pip3 install -U gita`. You can find more information on [github](https://github.com/nosarthur/gita).

[image]